# Microsoft 2011 for Mac

Tags: imac, ms-office, microsoft

For school I have to create a Powerpoint presentation and I am experiencing a problem. My teacher asked me to use a Text Effect of **Gradient Fill - Black, Outline - White, Outer Shadow** and when I try to hover the mouse over the text effects it will not show me the name of the effect.

Is it a problem with my mac? Should I report this to Microsoft? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the block of text you wish to apply the effect to.

On the top menu, click on `Format` and then `Font...`.

From here you can achieve the effects desired. View the screenshots below.

[image: Text Fill]

[image: Text Outline]

[image: Text Shadow]

Answer (score 2):

Select the text and right click to select "Format Text…" from the contextual menu.

- Click "Text Fill" to find the "Gradient" settings.
- Click "Text Line" to set outline colors.
- Click "Text Shadow" to set shadow settings for the selected text.